# Call functions doesnt work in onCreate android

Tags: android

I have two functions with be names of rounOne() and roundTwo(). In both of these functions somethings happen and then an AlertDialog will be appeared. in my onCreate function, I want to call these functions like this: roundOne() , roundTwo(), roundTwo(), roundOne(). I mean that first, roundOne function executes and after pressing ok in alertdialog, function roundTwo() executes and so on. But it doesnt work in the way that I implemented it. Can anybody guide me?

Comment: It is not short. I just wanna know about the way that I should call my functions. roundOne and roundTwo are void.

Comment: @khatereh: It sounds as if you want to open an alert dialog from `onCreate()`. But that's the wrong place to do it. Furthermore, please describe what happens. We cannot imagine what *it doesnt work in the way...* means.

Answer (score 1):

> When you call RoundOne() you are showing AlertDialog in it Right? now you want to call roundTwo if user press any button.

In Android It executes rest of ur code and don't wait AlertDialog to end up. If you want to call any Method on Button/ok Click on Dialog, call your method from Dialog on Button click itself.

Comment: Yes I tried it before. But it didnt work in this way. I used dialog.dismiss(); before calling my another function. Is it any way to finish current function after pressing ok and call all functions from onCreate?

Comment: No you can not call it continuously.. call methods from Dialog,, Use Dialog instead of AlertDialog